# How to process the audio signal from the microphone?

Tags: python-3.x, audio

I have a code that receives an audio signal from the microphone and broadcasts it to the speakers, how can I process this signal, for example, reduce the tone and the like? This signal looks like this:

```
...
 [-0.10275269]
 [-0.10058594]
 [-0.09945679]]
[[-0.09802246]
 [-0.09729004]
 [-0.09899902]
 ...
```

Code:

```
import keyboard
import sounddevice as sd



def callback(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    outdata[:] = indata
    print(indata)

with sd.Stream(device=(None, None), channels=1, callback=callback):
    print('#' * 80)
    print('press q quit')
    print('#' * 80)
    keyboard.wait('q')
```

I tried to find libraries suitable for this task, but I failed.